# Swift CollectionView section categories

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am attempting to create a cocktail menu within a collection view. The data from the API has the cocktails grouped into categories (sweet, fruity etc) and the image for the category outside of the cocktail array. The layout I am wanting to achieve is in the image below.

Using the code I have written I have managed to group the cocktails successfully however I am unsure as to how to display the category image as the first cell in each section.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Data from the API:

```
[ 
   { 
      "signatureCocktailSets":[ 
         { 
            "cocktails":[ 
               { 
                  "id":1,
                  "cocktail":1,
                  "category":1,
                  "image":"*****/fruity.png",
                  "cocktailid":1,
                  "name":"Fruit & Fibre",
                  "description":"Throwing fresh Raspberry Gin and Black Raspberry Liquer together, mixed with Passionfruit Puree to give a crisp and fruity taste.",
                  "ingredients":"\nEdinburgh Raspberry\nChambord\nApple juice\nPassionfruit puree\nSugar syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Fruit+%26+Fibre.jpg",
                  "property":"Fruity"
               },
               { 
                  "id":1,
                  "cocktail":2,
                  "category":1,
                  "image":"*****/fruity.png",
                  "cocktailid":2,
                  "name":"Beach Blend",
                  "description":"A perfect balance of Coconut Rum Pineapple Juice and Banana Liquer takes you back to the Sunny Beaches.",
                  "ingredients":"Malibu\nPineapple juice\nBanana liqueur\nCaramel syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Beach+Blend.jpg",
                  "property":"Fruity"
               },
               { 
                  "id":1,
                  "cocktail":3,
                  "category":1,
                  "image":"*****/fruity.png",
                  "cocktailid":3,
                  "name":"Passion Berry",
                  "description":"Passionfruit based flavour with the warmth of Gin we all Love. Shaken with fresh Raspberries to add then extra rich fruity taste.",
                  "ingredients":"Tanqueray\nPassoa\nPassionfruit puree\nLemon Juice\nFresh raspberries\nSugar syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Passion+Berry.jpg",
                  "property":"Fruity"
               }
            ],
            "SignatureCocktailSetImageURL":"*****/fruity.png"
         },
         { 
            "cocktails":[ 
               { 
                  "id":2,
                  "cocktail":4,
                  "category":2,
                  "image":"*****/indulgent.png",
                  "cocktailid":4,
                  "name":"Forest Gataux",
                  "description":"A rich taste of berries, with an almond flavour at the end. The perfect dessert, go ahead treat yourself. ",
                  "ingredients":"Chambord\nSmirnoff\nDisaronno\nStrawberry syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Forest+Gateaux.jpg",
                  "property":"Indulgent"
               },
               { 
                  "id":2,
                  "cocktail":5,
                  "category":2,
                  "image":"*****/indulgent.png",
                  "cocktailid":5,
                  "name":"Mint Moment",
                  "description":"A Minty taste with a rich coffee and cream base brings Indulgent Nights to life  ",
                  "ingredients":"Baileys\nCr\u00e8me de menthe\nKahlua",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Mint+Moment.jpg",
                  "property":"Indulgent"
               },
               { 
                  "id":2,
                  "cocktail":6,
                  "category":2,
                  "image":"*****/indulgent.png",
                  "cocktailid":6,
                  "name":"Nutty Monk",
                  "description":"A smooth Hazlenut and Cream blend will leave your palette feeling enlivened ",
                  "ingredients":"Baileys\nFrangelico\nKahlua",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Nutty+Monk.jpg",
                  "property":"Indulgent"
               }
            ],
            "SignatureCocktailSetImageURL":"*****/indulgent.png"
         },
         { 
            "cocktails":[ 
               { 
                  "id":3,
                  "cocktail":7,
                  "category":3,
                  "image":"*****/sour.png",
                  "cocktailid":7,
                  "name":"Tropic Tequila",
                  "description":"Tequila Fan? This sour blend of Patron Silver Tequila, Pineapple Juice will leave a fruity kick to remember",
                  "ingredients":"Patron Silver\nPineapple juice\nLemon Juice\nSugar syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Tropic+Sour.jpg",
                  "property":"Sour"
               },
               { 
                  "id":3,
                  "cocktail":8,
                  "category":3,
                  "image":"*****/sour.png",
                  "cocktailid":8,
                  "name":"Sloe & Sour",
                  "description":"Blended with Gordon's Sloe Gin, these bitter berries are ephasised by the Lemon Juice, a zesty tingle to your tastebuds",
                  "ingredients":"Gordon's Sloe\nPassoa\nPassionfruit puree\nLemon juice\nSugar syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Sloe+%26+Sour.jpg",
                  "property":"Sour"
               },
               { 
                  "id":3,
                  "cocktail":9,
                  "category":3,
                  "image":"*****/sour.png",
                  "cocktailid":9,
                  "name":"Kentucky Twist",
                  "description":"Like the Buffalo, this is a strong bodied cocktail. Blending up a fruity yet sour edge, giving just a slight nudge but nothing you can't handle",
                  "ingredients":"Buffalo Trace\nChambord\nGordon's Pink\nLemon juice\nSugar syrup\nApple juice",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Kentucky+Twist+600x600.jpg",
                  "property":"Sour"
               }
            ],
            "SignatureCocktailSetImageURL":"*****/sour.png"
         },
         { 
            "cocktails":[ 
               { 
                  "id":4,
                  "cocktail":10,
                  "category":4,
                  "image":"*****/sweet.png",
                  "cocktailid":10,
                  "name":"Rhubard Passion",
                  "description":"Built around a poupular flavour, this bitter Rhubarb has been sweetened up with Passionfruit to give you a refreshing and satisyfing flavour",
                  "ingredients":"Slingsby Rhubarb\nPassoa\nLemon Juice\nSugar syrup\nSoda top",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Rhubarb+Passion.jpg",
                  "property":"Sweet"
               },
               { 
                  "id":4,
                  "cocktail":11,
                  "category":4,
                  "image":"*****/sweet.png",
                  "cocktailid":11,
                  "name":"Tai Spice",
                  "description":"Spiced Dark Rum, sweetened with and almond and orange Liqueur Based upon a Tiki Classic this sweet selection with leave you feeling savoured",
                  "ingredients":"Kracken\nDisaronno\nCointreau\nLime juice\nSugar syrup",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Tai+Spice.jpg",
                  "property":"Sweet"
               },
               { 
                  "id":4,
                  "cocktail":12,
                  "category":4,
                  "image":"*****/sweet.png",
                  "cocktailid":12,
                  "name":"Fibre-Day",
                  "description":"If you like fresh fruit this is the one for you, Kurrants, Watermelon, Peach and crisp Apple. This is bound to take you back to that cocktail bar abroad. ",
                  "ingredients":"Absolut Kurrant\nMidori\nArchers\nApple juice\nLemon juice",
                  "cocktailImage":"*****/Fibre+Day.jpg",
                  "property":"Sweet"
               }
            ],
            "SignatureCocktailSetImageURL":"*****/sweet.png"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

What I currently have:

[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

struct cocktailsStruct: Decodable {
    var cocktailid: Int
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var ingredients: String
    var cocktailImage: URL
}

struct signatureCocktailSetsStruct: Decodable {
    var cocktails:[cocktailsStruct]
    var SignatureCocktailSetImageURL: String
}

struct signatureCocktailStruct : Decodable {
    var signatureCocktailSets: [signatureCocktailSetsStruct]
}

var signatureCocktailArray: [signatureCocktailStruct]!

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var numberOfSections: Int = 4


    @IBOutlet var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "cocktail", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.******")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, reponse, error) in

            do {
            signatureCocktailArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([signatureCocktailStruct].self, from: data!)
            print(signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets[0].SignatureCocktailSetImageURL)
                print(signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets.count)
                self.numberOfSections = signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets.count
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        collectionViewHeight.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return numberOfSections
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width / 2, height: self.collectionView.frame.width / 2)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cocktail
        if(signatureCocktailArray != nil){
        cell.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets[indexPath.section].cocktails[indexPath.row].cocktailImage)"), completed: nil)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go step by step

1) Update number of items, based on the response from server

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets[indexPath.section].cocktails.count + 1
    }
```

2) check for the indexPath.row if zero then set the default

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cocktail
        if(signatureCocktailArray != nil) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets[indexPath.section]. SignatureCocktailSetImageURL)"), completed: nil) 
        } else {
        cell.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(signatureCocktailArray[0].signatureCocktailSets[indexPath.section].cocktails[indexPath.row-1].cocktailImage)"), completed: nil)
        }}
        return cell
    }
```

**NOTE:** If there is didSelect method implemented then, consider putting the condition there too, to avoid crash

Hope it helps